# How make Combine's flatMap to complete overall stream?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have some code like this

```swift
func a() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
    Future<Void, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print(1)
            promise(.success(()))
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func b() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
    Future<Void, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print(2)
            promise(.success(()))
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var tempBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1)

subject
    .flatMap({ _ in a() })
    .flatMap({ _ in b() })
    .print()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
        tempBag.removeAll()
    }, receiveValue: {  })
    .store(in: &tempBag)
```

So, I have some uncompletable subject in the root of the stream and some completable publishers in flatMap operator. I want the overall stream to complete when the last flatMap's publisher completes. So, I want the console to look like this:

```
receive subscription: (FlatMap)
request unlimited
1
2
receive value: (())
receive finished
```

but actual result is

```
receive subscription: (FlatMap)
request unlimited
1
2
receive value: (())
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you aware of how a `flatMap` behaves? You seem to misunderstand how it works. `flatMap(f)` replaces _every_ element `x` that its upstream publishes with all the elements that the publisher `f(x)` publishes. As a consequence, `flatMap` never completes if its upstream never completes. If you just want 1 element, how about adding `prefix(1)` after the last `flatMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your `Subject` (the `CurrentValueSubject`) never finishes so the entire chain never completes.  What you need is a publisher that emits a single value then completes at the top of your sequence, and an intermediate that waits until all the publishers it is tracking complete before finishing itself.

You already have a publisher that does one thing then completes... it's returned by `a()`.  To wait until both `a()` and `b()` complete you can use `combineLatest` since a the publisher it creates won't finish until all the publishers it combines finish.  The whole thing looks like:

```
a()
.combineLatest(b())
.print()
.sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
    tempBag.removeAll()
}, receiveValue: { _ in () })
.store(in: &tempBag)
```

with the output

```
receive subscription: (CombineLatest)
request unlimited
1
2
receive value: (((), ()))
receive finished
```